# Map of Quotient Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces

Let $V,W,V',W'$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces. Given linear maps $T_1: V \to V'$ and $T_2: W \to W'$, what is the proper map diagram to get a map $$T: V /W \to V'/W'?$$

I tried to expand out a universal property diagram but was having a bit of trouble writing it down.

Comment: Such a map exists only if $T(W)\subseteq W'$.

Comment: Ah yes I should have added that.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli In particular the set up I was looking at is the de rham cohomology functor...from the pullback of differential forms to de rham groups

Comment: I gather $\left.T_1\right\rvert_W=T_2$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli In fact $T_1 = T_2$